# Rad Grid check/uncheck check box column On RowDataBound

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik

I have rad grid with GridTemplateColumn which contains a checkbox.
I am trying to check / uncheck this check boxes OnRowDataBound event.
This is my grid:

```
<telerik:RadGrid runat="server" ID="RadGrid1" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true"
        AllowFilteringByColumn="true" PageSize="5">
        <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" ClientDataKeyNames="Id">
            <PagerStyle Mode="NumericPages" AlwaysVisible="true" />
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridImageColumn DataType="System.String" DataImageUrlFields="Image" AlternateText="User image"
                    UniqueName="Image" DataImageUrlFormatString="/{0}"
                    ImageAlign="Middle" ImageHeight="50px" ImageWidth="50px" AllowFiltering="false" HeaderText="">
                </telerik:GridImageColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="UserName" HeaderText="User Name" UniqueName="UserName"
                    DataType="System.String">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="" AllowFiltering="false" UniqueName="CheckColumn">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox Text="" ID="ckUser" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

            </Columns>
        </MasterTableView>
        <ClientSettings>
            <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" />
            <ClientEvents OnRowDataBound="grdUsrs_RowDataBind" />
            <DataBinding Location="/SecuHostapi/Security" CountPropertyName="Count" ResponseType="JSON" DataPropertyName="Items">
                <DataService Type="OData" TableName="User/GetforGrid" />
            </DataBinding>
        </ClientSettings>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

js

```
function grdUsrs_RowDataBind(sender, args) {
        
  var td = args.get_item().get_cell("CheckColumn"); 
  dataItem = args.get_dataItem();
  btnEdit.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked = true;
  }
```

I also tried

```
$(btnEdit).find('#ckUser').prop('checked', true);
```

but also still no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that I am using bootstrab 3 
which change the check box html.
here is the solution
$(btnEdit).find('#ckUser').find('span').addClass('checked');

[check/uncheck bootstrap checkboxes with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25143083/check-uncheck-bootstrap-checkboxes-with-jquery)