# check/uncheck bootstrap checkboxes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I've made another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25123126/select-all-checkboxes-with-jquery-not-working) yesterday and had no success with it. I will try now to reorder de idea and to ask  again since I can't find the solution for this (I'm a newbie and I'm trying really hard).

The thing is that I'm working with this template based on Bootstrap, and this is the code that I can see directly from one of the files and that I'm using on my project:

*html snippet:*

```
<div class="hide" id="states">
  <div class="control-group">                           
    <label class="control-label">Seleccione</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <label class="checkbox span4">
          <input type="checkbox" value="all" id="allstates" name="all"/>Todas
        </label>

        <label class="checkbox span4">
          <input class="states" type="checkbox" value="Caba" id="" name="st[]"/>Ciudad Autónoma de Buenos Aires
        </label>

        <label class="checkbox span4">
          <input class="states" type="checkbox" value="Buenos Aires" id="" name="st[]"/> Buenos Aires
        </label>

        <label class="checkbox span4">
          <input class="states" type="checkbox" value="Catamarca" id="" name="st[]"/> Catamarca
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

*After lot of searching I have founded when inspecting it that my code looks like this (snippet):*

```
<div class="controls">
  <label class="checkbox span4">
    <div class="checker" id="uniform-allstates">
      <span>
        <input type="checkbox" value="all" id="allstates" name="all">
      </span>
    </div>Todas
  </label>

  <label class="checkbox span4">
    <div class="checker">
      <span>
        <input class="states" type="checkbox" value="Caba" id="" name="st[]">                          
       </span>
    </div> Ciudad Autónoma de Buenos Aires
  </label>

  <label class="checkbox span4">
    <div class="checker">
      <span>
        <input class="states" type="checkbox" value="Buenos Aires" id="" name="st[]">                           
      </span>
    </div> Buenos Aires
  </label>

  <label class="checkbox span4">
    <div class="checker">
      <span>
        <input class="states" type="checkbox" value="Catamarca" id="" name="st[]">                             
      </span>
    </div> Catamarca
  </label>
</div>
```

As you can see, another div and another span are added (seriously don't know why or how) so I'm guessing now it's some DOM problem the one I'm having.

*This is snippet of my js file:*

```
$('#allstates').click(function() {
  $('.checkbox').find('span').addClass('checked');
});
```

So this function selects ALL the checkboxes I have (even though the ones that I don't want because they belong to another category).

I want to know why the div and span are added and how to select only the checkboxes that I want.

For that I've been trying code like this but no success:

**test 1**

```
$('#allstates').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('span input').attr('checked', true);
  } else {
    $('span input').attr('checked', false);
  }
});
```

**test2**

```
$('#allstates').click(function() {
  $(".states").prop("checked",$("#allstates").prop("checked"))
});
```

and so other ones that I erased.

**NOTE:** No js errors are being displayed when inspecting

Comment: $('#checkboxId').prop('checked'); from https://stackoverflow.com/a/28604443/1225421

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since I mentioned that this function checked all the checkboxes I had (even though  the ones  that were not supposed to be checked), I've been trying to look for the solution:

```
$('#allstates').click(function() {
  $('.checkbox').find('span').addClass('checked');
});
```

But this is not what I wanted. I mentioned also that I noticed that the code was "different" when inspecting it (in Chrome with F12). So as @thecbuilder said, it changes in order to add style.

I realized that since code is changing... I had to change the class (checkbox) from which I was starting the "span tag" search, so I change class checkbox to id states and this is the result:

```
$('#allstates').click(function() {
  if($(this).attr("checked")){
    $('#states').find('span').addClass('checked');        
  }else{
    $('#states').find('span').removeClass('checked');
  }    
});
```

Now it finally works.

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32266101/uncheck-table-row-in-bootstrap-table-on-specific-condition

Answer (score 12):

Also it is important to add prop to true on selecting checkboxes:

```
$("#checkAll").click(function(){
   var check = $(this).prop('checked');
   if(check == true) {
     $('.checker').find('span').addClass('checked');
     $('.checkbox').prop('checked', true);
   } else {
     $('.checker').find('span').removeClass('checked');
     $('.checkbox').prop('checked', false);
   }
});
```

Comment: Manually handling the checkbox checked state on click has helped me working around a weird issue on my iOS (12.1+) web app, where the browser was rendering the inverted state of my checkbox 

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for code like:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#allstates").on("change", function()
    {
        var checked = $(this).prop("checked");

        $(this).parents(".controls")
            .first()
            .find("input[type=checkbox]")
            .prop("checked", checked);
    });
});
```

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/K6MD3/1/)

When the state of the checkbox with the id `allstates` changes, get the checkbox value, find the first parent html element with a class called `controls` and then only update all the checkboxes in that element with the value of checked.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I know it works on fiddle, but it's not working on my code..

Comment: I [updated the fiddle with your exact html](http://jsfiddle.net/K6MD3/1/) and it appears to work.  What isn't working about it?

Comment: Yes I know, I build code by myself that worked on fiddle but didn't in my code. I don't know what can possible be..the js code I posted does work but selects all checkboxes even though the ones I don't want to

Comment: thanks for the concern. I now this works, but doesn't work in my case. I came up with the solution though

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32266101/uncheck-table-row-in-bootstrap-table-on-specific-condition

Answer (score 2):

Simple bootstrap checkbox

```
<label><input type="checkbox" value="">Option 1</label>
```

When debug in Chrome dev tool, label look like
https://tinker.press/images/bootstrap-checkbox-label-2017-01-17_084755.png

To toogle checkbox state just set `true|false` on `lable.control.checked`

```
label.control.checked = false; //uncheck
label.control.checked = true; //check
```

Video demo https://youtu.be/3qEMFd9bcd8

Comment: sadly this doesn't work when you're using the checkbox and radio buttons: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons

Comment: video tutorial is quite useful